# C#: Class/Method That Builds Connection

Tags: c#

Completely new to `C#`.

In my app, several buttons will connection to `MySql` and pass information to and from it.  Each button has it's own connection string, which I find redundant and was curious if there was a way in C# to build a `Class` or `Method`, holding the connection string, and call the connection in each button, instead of establishing the connection, then calling it.

I tried building a `Public Method` which used `MySqlConnection mycon` parameter and had it return `mycon`, however, in the other buttons, it saw mycon as a method, not an object.  From there I tried a `Class` (using syntax from dotnetperls and other sites), which have yielded other errors about type.  Clearly, being new to this, I am approaching the wrong syntax to build a `Class` and `Method`, though I'm assuming that since a `Method` will be an action, I am actually seeking a class that will hold the objects and allow other parts of the program to access it.

See below pseudo-code as an example:

**Current**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection();
mycon.ConnectionString = "Connection";

mycon.Open();
// Code
mycon.Close();

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection();
mycon.ConnectionString = "Connection";

mycon.Open();
// Code
mycon.Close();

}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Connection";

mycon.Open();
// Code
mycon.Close();

}
```

**Goal:**

```
Some Class
{

//MySqlConnection parameters establish mycon

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

mycon.Open();
// Code
mycon.Close();

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

mycon.Open();
// Code
mycon.Close();

}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

mycon.Open();
// Code
mycon.Close();

}
```

Note: I am aware of the `XML` approach (and have used it in another one of my programs), but am trying to see if there's a `Class/Method` approach.

Comment: You should be wrapping all your connections in `using`'s.

Comment: And also probably not doing directly it in your UI's event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest having a method (can probably be static, and exist in a place accessible from anywhere in your code) that deals with all the details of getting a connection, and returns it. Then anywhere you need a connection, call that method.

```
class SomeClass
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var conn = Utilities.GetConnection())
        {
            conn.Open();
            // Code
        }
    }
}
public static class Utilities
{
    public static MySqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Connection";
        return conn;
    }
}
```

And use `using` to ensure that the connection is always closed. It's usually good practice to do this with any `IDisposable` that you use.

For some info/duscussion on whether `Open()` should be in `GetConnection()` or not, see [using statement with connection.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316981/using-statement-with-connection-open)

Comment: Absolutely beautiful; saved a ton of code and gives me some ideas on how to leverage this.  Also, good point on the OPEN, it's kind of redundant itself since, when I call this method, I'll be opening a connection!

Answer (score 3):

Use a static method to create connection, and `using` shorthand to close/dispose it:

```
SomeClass
{
   public static MySqlConnection CreateConnection()
   {
       MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection();
       mycon.ConnectionString = "Connection";
       mycon.Open();
       return mycon;
   }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = SomeClass.CreateConnection())
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: If `Open()` throws, I think there might be resources that aren't properly disposed.

Comment: @TimS. - hm, need to look at it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316981/using-statement-with-connection-open has more info - the accepted answer there is that you shouldn't open a connection before returning it. Kind of a pointless, subjective thing, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SomeClass : IDisposable
{
    SqlConnection conn;

    public SomeClass
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection("some connectionstring");
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        conn.Open()
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        conn.Close()
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        conn.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this class use `conn`, or how would another class use this one?

Comment: Well, by calling this class, you use the SqlConnection indirectly.

Comment: `conn` is private; if I have an instance of `SomeClass`, I can't do anything with the connection except open, close, and dispose.

Comment: You can add methods to the class that uses that connection. If you want to use the connection directly, you can either make it a public property, or just create instances of it wherever you need it. As a public property, you could declare it: `public SqlConnection Connection {get; set;}`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
public class DataBase
{
    private static string DEFAULT_CONNECTION_STRING = "*your connection string*";
    private string connectionString;
    private DbProviderFactory factory;

    public DataBase()
    {
            connectionString = DEFAULT_CONNECTION_STRING;
            factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySql");
    }

    public IDataReader GetData(string sql)
    {
            using(var conn = factory.CreateConnection())
            using(var command = factory.CreateCommand())
            {
                    command.CommandText = sql;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    conn.ConnectionString = this.connectionString;
                    conn.Open();
                    command.Connection = conn;
                    return cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
    }
}
```